# What is the difference between C# marshaled struct pointers?

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

Ok, this is working:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 28)]
public unsafe struct HandleProxy
{
    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public JSValueType _ValueType; // JSValueType is an enum

    [FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 _ManagedObjectID; 

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public void* _NativeEngineProxy;

    [FieldOffset(16), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 _EngineID;

    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public void* _Handle;
}

[DllImport("Proxy")]
public static extern void DisposeHandleProxy(HandleProxy* handle);
```

... and this does not ...

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 20)]
public unsafe struct ValueProxy
{
    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public JSValueType _ValueType; // 32-bit type value.

    [FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public bool _Boolean;

    [FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 _Integer;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public double _Number;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public void* _String;
}

[DllImport("Proxy")]
public static extern void DisposeValueProxy(ValueProxy* valueProxy);
```

So, what's the difference? I'm missing something. A call to "DisposeValueProxy() gives the following error:

"Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Pointers cannot reference marshaled structures.  Use ByRef instead."

(and yes, I can simply use IntPtr/void* instead of "ValueProxy*" but that's not my point).

A call to "DisposeHandleProxy()" works fine.

Let's see if someone can figure this one out. ;)

Comment: How do you define "not working"?

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot understand why you are using explicit layout here. I also don't see the need for `unsafe`.

Comment: It's simple, I'm accessing values in a union from the native side. The field I read from depends on the type. This is to support dynamic values from a native library (not written by me). The unsafe modifier is required because a pointer is there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A struct must be *blittable* to create a pointer to it.  The second struct is not blittable, the *bool* field is the troublemaker.  You'd have to make it a byte or int instead, depending on the intention.

An overview of what types are blittable in .NET is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx).

The exception message's advice is a very sound one, declare the argument as `ref ValueProxy` instead to leave it up to the pinvoke marshaller to create a copy of the struct with the desired layout.

Comment: You sir are awesome, thanks. ;) I figured bool was a "sure thing" (because I already knew of issues with non-blittable types) but I hadn't realized bool was not one of them.  This I think is a really stupid situation, but I guess since natively there could be 8-bit or 32-bit bools (depending on the compiler) it perhaps makes a bit of sense. ;) It's a shame, as usual, MS makes it hard to find out what's going on with those useless error messages. It should have been something like "Structure is not blittable". ;)